# How can I sort multiple lists by sorting one list?

Tags: python, list, sorting

So I have a question related to lists and assigned values. I have 5 customers and some artificially created random variables (price and costs). I want to assign these values to customer 1, 2 ... 5 such that these values are fixed to the customer.

So customer 1 should have a randomly created value for price created with mean 10 and standard deviation of 1. This customer should have a randomly generated value for costs with mean 8 and standard deviation of 1.

This should be done for each customer. How can I code this for each customer (such that I do not have to create for each customer a new line with price[...] and costs[...]? And the next question is, how can I sort by costs such that the other variables are also sorted? So customer 4 has the highest costs (= 9), then customer 1, 3, 5 and lastly customer 3. Then I also want to be able to sort the other price by this ranking. My code is as follows:

```
avg_price = [10 3 5 5 8] 
avg_costs = [8 3 5 9 4]
std_dev_price = [1 2 1 1 2]
std_dev_costs = [1 1 2 2 1]
num_reps = 10
price0 = np.random.normal(avg_price[0], std_dev_price[0], num_reps)
costs0 = np.random.normal(avg_costs[0], std_dev_costs[0], num_reps)
...
price4 = np.random.normal(avg_price[4], std_dev_price[4], num_reps)
costs4 = np.random.normal(avg_costs[4], std_dev_costs[4], num_reps)
```

Comment: You are going to have to transfer your data into a different format.

Comment: What about `price = [np.random.normal(avg_price[0], std_dev_price[0], num_reps) for i in range(5)]`?

Answer (score 0):

For creating the normalize arrays, you can use an array and loop. To sort all lists by the values in a single list, you can merge them into a dataframe then sort the dataframe.

Try this code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

avg_price = [10, 3, 5, 5, 8] 
avg_costs = [8, 3, 5, 9, 4]
std_dev_price = [1, 2, 1, 1, 2]
std_dev_costs = [1, 1, 2, 2, 1]

print('Start:')
print(' avg_price',avg_price,'\n','avg_costs',avg_costs,'\n','std_dev_price',std_dev_price,'\n','std_dev_costs',std_dev_costs,'\n')

num_reps = 10
price = []
costs = []
for i in range(len(avg_price)):
    price.append(np.random.normal(avg_price[i], std_dev_price[i], num_reps))
    costs.append(np.random.normal(avg_costs[i], std_dev_costs[i], num_reps))
    
# merge lists to dataframe
dd = {'avg_price':avg_price,'avg_costs':avg_costs,'std_dev_price':std_dev_price,'std_dev_costs':std_dev_costs,'price':price,'costs':costs}
df = pd.DataFrame(dd) 

# sort all columns by avg_costs
df = df.sort_values(by=['avg_costs'], ascending=False)  

# revert back to lists
avg_price = df['avg_price'].to_list()
avg_costs = df['avg_costs'].to_list()
std_dev_price = df['std_dev_price'].to_list()
std_dev_costs = df['std_dev_costs'].to_list()
price = df['price'].to_list()
costs = df['costs'].to_list()

print('Sorted by avg costs:')
print(' avg_price',avg_price,'\n','avg_costs',avg_costs,'\n','std_dev_price',std_dev_price,'\n','std_dev_costs',std_dev_costs,'\n')

print('Full Dataframe:')
print(df)
```

Output (aligned)

```
 Start:
 avg_price     [10, 3, 5, 5, 8]
 avg_costs     [8,  3, 5, 9, 4]
 std_dev_price [1,  2, 1, 1, 2]
 std_dev_costs [1,  1, 2, 2, 1]
 
 Sorted by avg costs:
 avg_price     [5, 10, 5, 8, 3]
 avg_costs     [9, 8,  5, 4, 3]
 std_dev_price [1, 1,  1, 2, 2]
 std_dev_costs [2, 1,  2, 1, 1]

 Full Datframe:
   avg_price  avg_costs  std_dev_price  std_dev_costs                                              price                                              costs
3          5          9              1              2  [2.5092028090378355, 4.81567722966441, 5.49058...  [10.563731356333232, 6.647727831982642, 8.0096...
0         10          8              1              1  [9.341336323005978, 9.810670988947805, 10.7077...  [7.339563107482252, 8.790936460961769, 8.40626...
2          5          5              1              2  [5.656265155737828, 4.975811559532342, 6.49261...  [1.6639841191325848, 3.691022076817463, 7.0424...
4          8          4              2              1  [7.868428684276111, 8.65633376629758, 11.67775...  [4.141047169505752, 4.25009712746727, 2.993419...
1          3          3              2              1  [2.920446641165024, 3.958967186635695, 3.31161...  [3.5024403403983557, 3.7703884020352803, 2.708...
```